# Media Player not working correctly in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i am trying to develope an app where the user selects a song from the list and then the song's name is stored in the preferences. 
at a particular time the applications opens and is required to play the song earlier saved by the user. 
i tried this code, but it is giving me an error.

```
String song;
MediaPlayer mp;
SharedPreferences prefs;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarmdetails);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
               prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
               song = prefs.getString("song_title", null);
               playSong();
        }

private void playSong() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (!song.equals(null)) {

            try {   
            mp.setAudioSessionId(mp.getAudioSessionId());
                      mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(song));

                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

    }
```

this is the activity where i save the song in the preferences:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            myPref.edit().putString("song_title",l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()).commit();


            finish();
        }
```

i made a list by taking all the songs that are stored in the sdcard. so all the songs that come in the list DO EXISTS. the selected song is then stored in the preferences.

when i run this,i get the following error

```
05-22 12:22:38.400: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25975): native_setup
05-22 12:22:38.400: V/MediaPlayer(25975): constructor
05-22 12:22:38.410: V/MediaPlayer(25975): setListener
05-22 12:22:38.415: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25975): get_session_id()
05-22 12:22:38.415: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25975): set_session_id(): 4165
05-22 12:22:38.415: V/MediaPlayer(25975): MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(4165)
05-22 12:22:38.420: I/MediaPlayer(25975): path is null
05-22 12:22:38.425: D/MediaPlayer(25975): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-22 12:22:38.430: E/MediaPlayer(25975): Unable to to create media player
05-22 12:22:38.430: I/System.out(25975): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Please help! 
thanks

Comment: It says right there that 'path is null'

Comment: You want to get sure that the song is not null, so You have to set if(song!=null) instead of (if(!song.equals(null)). Also, please Show us how You save the preferences

Comment: is it possible that You can Show us an example how the String Looks like?

Comment: 05-22 12:22:38.415: I/System.out(25975): the song and id got is=Munni Badnaam. i get this when i print the song got from the preferences.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the exact String that is given by MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(song));

Comment: content://media/Munni Badnaam/audio/media.....this is the given string

Comment: Could you please try with `MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(song))` as `getContentUri` is for a volume name as captured here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#getContentUri%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i got the answer to my problem. this is to help other people who have the same problem.

i just changed the playSong() function to this-->

```
                     myPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                myPlayer.prepare();
                myPlayer.start();
                myPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

thats it. :)

Comment: can you suggest me for How to manage seekbar with post handler in listview ?